# Illustrator. Spacing between parallel lines of art brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

Hello everyone I am new to Adobe illustrator and I am trying to create a brush that allows me to draw a path with double parallel lines. I have created an art brush and everything works correctly, the problem is that when I modify the thickness of my path, I would like my 2 lines to remain thick and what would be modified was the space between them, this can be achieved somehow mode. Thank you!![image]

Comment: thats what brushes do. use offset effect instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Offset Path** effect.

In the *Appearance* panel, click the *fx* button and choose *Path > Offset Path*.

That way the path becomes like a closed object which then gets the stroke applied. So the *Offset* controls the distance between lines and the *Stroke Weight* only affects the thickness of the parallel lines.

If the path intersects itself the lower lines won't be visible. Can be good or bad depending on what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the end closing strokes seen with Offset Path... And the scale issues present in brushes....

Another option is to merely use **2 strokes** stacked on top of each other in the **Appearance Panel**. Set the black stroke thicker, and the white stroke thinner.

[image]

The *problem* with this method can be the inner stroke color. It *may* be possible to simply use any background color (as opposed to white) for the thinner stroke. It depends upon the artwork.

*However*, if you do this and set the entire object's **Blend Mode** to `Multiply` or `Darken`, that inner white stroke visually disappears.....

[image]

This keeps the object structure as a *single path* to alter. It's then a simple matter to change the stroke weights if desired.

[image]

And you *can* use the **Width Tool** on just *one* of the strokes. I thinned the white stroke on the curve below with the Width Tool.

[image]

Or merely set a **Stroke Profile** on the **Stroke Panel** for one of the strokes...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A) there's a simple black curve and a pair of green lines. The line pair is dragged to brushes and set to be an art brush.

B) The art brush is applied to the black curve

C) The stroke width of B is modified, in this case it's done with the width tool. The width of green curves doesn't stay the same and you obviously do not like it.

D) This is what I think you expect, only the distance of the green curves varies

Two solutions exist:

1. Expand the appearance of D and change the wanted stroke width. The drawback is that expand appearance creates 2 separate paths, it's no more a single curve.
2. Apply to the green line pair Object > Compound path > Make, do it before you drag it to the brushes. The result (D) is still an editable single path.

Offset path and inserting another stroke with offset are other possibilities which work if the distance between the lines stays the same. I used the width tool to offer something more general.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried option 2 to continue having the path editable, but I can't get the lines to stay the same thickness and only change the spacing...

I must add the compound path before creating the brush, right? and adds it to each of the lines or to the group of both.